# How to encode array image with json?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I want to ask  something,

```
<?php 
require "connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM main";
$sql=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$ray = array();
echo"<table>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo"<tr>";
        $ray[]= array(
        echo"<td>";?> 'gambar'=><img src="<?php $row["gambar"], ?>" height="100" width="100"><?php echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>"; 'id' => $row["id"], echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";  'nama'=>$row["nama"], echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";  'harga'=>$row["harga"] echo "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
        ));}
        echo "</table>";

        echo json_encode($ray);
        ?>
```

this is my php configuration. I don't know 
why the result seems like this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ')' in /home/u220924381/public_html/private_html/displaying.php on line 10
```

I'm a newbie, this is for my campus project. I tried many methods and it can't resolve my problem.

Comment: post your actual code not an image of your code

Comment: you cannot use `echo` inside an array.... many errors

Comment: @RamRaider so i have to delete the table that i create?

Comment: Why is this tagged android?